# rails Internationalization(I18n) string comparaison chinese probleme

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I try to compare a Chinese string with a value store in locale file
but i got a problem.

I store in my database a value selected by the user, the key/value is:

```
kind: "其他国家"
```

and when i try to get the value for ma comparaison i receive only : "其他国

the condition is very easy and work with the other language (English and French)

Here the condition :

```
if self.kind == I18n.t('countries.OC')
#do my thing
end
```

litteraly I get :

```
if "其他国 == "其他国家"
#do my thing
end
```

I try to find the best to correct this, the first thing i though was to check the value before my condition and set it with the good one.

But i would understand why that don't take all my string from my DB.

Thanks.